Commutation formula in spherical coordinates
Let $\Delta_\phi$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator in dimension $d$ on the sphere of radius $r$, that is $r^{-2}\partial^2_{\theta\theta}$ when $d=2$, $\frac{1}{r^2\sin \theta}\partial_\theta(\sin \theta \partial_\theta )+\frac{1}{r^2\sin \theta} \partial_{\phi\phi}$ when $d=3$, etc.
The laplacian in dimension $d$ can be written
$$
\Delta(f) = \frac{1}{r^{d-1}}\partial_r \left(r^{d-1}\partial_r f \right) + \Delta_\phi f.
$$
In cartesian coordinates, commutation between the directional derivative and the Laplacian are valid ($\partial_{x_i} \Delta = \Delta \partial_{x_i}$) . In spherical coordinates, it looks more messy, except in dimension 2 since $\partial_\theta$ has no $\theta$-dependent factor. What is (is there) the naturally commuting quantity? Is there a standard (clean) way to write the lower order terms obtained when performing the commutation?
For example,
$$
\partial_r \left(\Delta f\right) - \Delta \left(\partial_r f \right) = -(d-1) \partial_r f,
$$
simple enough, but for angular variables it is less clear when $d=3$:
$$
\partial_\phi \left(\Delta f\right) - \Delta \left(\partial_\phi f\right)
=0,$$
whereas
$$
\partial_\theta \left(\Delta f\right) - \Delta \left(\partial_\theta f \right) = -\frac{\cos 2\theta}{\sin^2\theta} \partial_\theta f -\frac{\cos \theta}{\sin^2\theta} \partial^2_{\phi\phi} f.
$$
I don't see a particular structure: maybe am I looking a the wrong object. Are there particular combinations of the angular variables that make the result look like something, with $d-1$ angular variables?
I am not particularly attached to the (hyper)spherical coordinate system: any representation which separate the radial direction from the tangential ones, and that allows simple commutation formulas, is very welcomed as a substitute.

The group of operations commuting with $-\Delta_{\theta,\phi}$ are the rotations of the sphere.
In  euclidean 3d, cartesian map, the differential operators commuting with the Laplacian on any sphere are the Lie-algebra of generators of the rotation group, the  scale invariant differential operators mixing only monomials of the same total degree
$$l_z = L_{(x,y)} = x (- i \ \partial_y) - y \ (-i \ \partial_x ), \quad \text {cylic}(x,y,z)$$
called angular momentum selfadjoint operators $\vec L = \vec x \times \vec p$. Their square is the spherical part of the Laplacian.
The spherical map
$$X(x,y,z) =r \ \left( \cos \phi \ \sin \theta , \sin \phi \ \sin \theta , \cos \theta \right) $$
at constant r=1 yields
$$(\partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z) = \frac{\partial(r,\theta,\phi)}{\partial(x,y,z)} \quad (\partial_r,\partial_\theta,\partial_\phi)$$
The inverse is best calculated in spherical coordinates by the differential in Mathematica, because the trigonometric compensations are trivial but voluminous
 Expand[Dt[
    r {Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], 
       Sin[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]],
       Cos[\[Theta]]}]] /. 
         {HoldPattern[Dt[x_]] :> \[DifferentialD]x}  

$$ \left(\begin{array}{l}\ -r \ d\phi  \sin \theta \ \sin (\phi ) \ + \ r d\theta  \cos (\theta ) \cos (\phi )\ + \ dr \sin (\theta ) \cos (\phi )\\ 
dr \ \sin \theta  \  \sin \phi  \ + \ r  d\phi  \  \sin \theta  \ \cos \phi  \ + 
\  r d\theta  \cos \theta \ \sin \phi \\ 
\cos (\theta )\ dr \ - \ r \ d\theta \ \sin \theta \end{array} \right)$$
The coefficient matrix is the inverse Jinv of the Jacobian
$$d \ r \left( \cos \phi \ \sin \theta , \sin \phi \ \sin \theta , \cos \theta \right)\quad = \quad \begin{array}{l,l} dr\quad  \left( \cos \phi \ \sin \theta , \sin \phi \ \sin \theta , \cos \theta \right) & + \\ 
 d\phi \quad \sin \theta (-\sin\phi , \cos \phi , 0) & + \\
 d \theta\ \quad  (\cos \phi \cos theta, \sin \phi \cos \theta, -\sin \theta)\end{array}$$
 Subscript[d, r,θ,φ ]= 
 (Inverse[D[Jinv, #] & /@ 
   {\[DifferentialD]r, 
    \[DifferentialD] θ, 
   \[DifferentialD] φ}] . 
       {Subscript[d, r], Subscript[d, θ], Subscript[d, φ]}) //
       FullSimplify

$$ d_{x,y,z} \ = \
\left(\begin{array}{l}
d_\theta \ \frac{1}{r} \  \cos \theta \  \cos \phi \ + \ d_r \ \sin \theta  \  \cos  \phi  \ - \ \frac{1}{r} \ d_{\phi } \ \csc \theta  \ \sin \phi \\
 d_r \ \sin \theta \  \sin \phi \ + \ \frac{1}{r} \  \ d_{\theta }\  \cos \theta \  \sin \phi \  + \ \frac{1}{r}\  \ d_{\phi } \ \csc \theta  \cos \phi \\
 d_r \cos \theta -\frac{1}{r} \ d_{\theta }\ \sin \theta  
\end{array} \right)
 $$
$$
L_{1,2} \ = \  i \left( X_1 \  (d_{r \theta ,\phi})_2\ - \ X_2\  (d_{r,\theta ,\phi})_1\right) \ \to \ i \ d_\phi $$
$$L_{2,3} \ = \  i \ \left(X_2 \ (d_{r,\theta ,\phi})_3 \ - \ X_3 \ ( d_{r,\theta ,\phi})_2 \right) \ \to  \ - i d_\theta \  \ \sin (\phi ) \ - i \ d_\phi \  \cot (\theta ) \ \cos (\phi )$$
$$L_{3,1} \ = \ i \  \left( X_3 \  (d_{r,\theta ,\phi})_1 \ - \ X_1 \ (d_{r,\theta ,\phi})_3\right)  \ \to \  i \ d_\theta \  \cos (\phi )\ - \ i \ d_\phi  \cot (\theta ) \ \sin (\phi )$$
$$L_1^2 \ + \ L_2^2 \  + \ L_3^2 \ = \ (\vec L)^2 \ = \ -\Delta_{\mathit{S}^2}$$
